# Laravel 5.2 uploaded file always null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to upload a file but it always returns null in my controller. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
FatalThrowableError in FileController.php line 25:
Fatal error: Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null
```

**Form**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="{{route('upload')}}">
    <label for="file_upload">Upload file</label>
    <input id="file_upload" type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

**Route (not calling any middleware)**

```
Route::post('file/upload', [
    'as'   => 'upload',
    'uses' => 'FileController@handleUpload',
]);
```

**Controller**

```
public function handleUpload(Request $request)
{
    $dir = sys_get_temp_dir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'adp';
    if (!file_exists($dir)) mkdir($dir);

    $extensions = AppPlatform::lists('package_extension')->toArray();

    $extension = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // this line throws the nullreference exception
    ...
}
```

I may have overlooked something very obvious but can't seem to find where the problem lies at the moment.

**EDIT**

When I look at the request in chrome's developer tools I can see the file is sent in the post request correctly.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryTLB02G6sLMEE2fMM
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="app-release.apk"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryTLB02G6sLMEE2fMM--
```

Comment: Try to dump `$_FILES` in `handleUpload()`. What is output?

Comment: did you get anything in dd($request->file('file'))?

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham returns an empty array

Comment: @sunilwananje returns null

Comment: Verify that server allows file upload. Check your `PHP.ini` and find `file_uploads = On` (Verify it's ON)

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham phpinfo() returns `file_uploads = On`

Comment: Did you tried by uploading an image?

Comment: @Muthu17 ok it turns out uploading images does work! this might be an issue with my webserver configuration...

Comment: So there is nothing problem in your configuration. Its works fine. Whats the size of your .apk file?

Comment: @Muthu17 turns out my `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` somehow reverted to the default values

Comment: Is it working fine now? or still facing the issue?

Comment: @Muthu17 yes it's fixed! thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @Fester Cool!. Happy coding.

Comment: try this.  $extension = $request->file->extension();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [Muthu17](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4049692/muthu17) I found out that `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` had been reset to 2M instead of the values I entered. So I added this to my webserver (Heroku) config and now it works!

```
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
post_max_size = 1024M
```